# Access subdomain folder directly from IP address

Tags: linux, networking, dns, apache-http-server, webserver

I have server located under X.Y.Z.C IP address. It runs Apache2. I've added additional domain to it, let us call it A. When I want to add something to it, I have to send files to A subdirectory in `public_html`. However I want to test my website, before I change DNSes to my server. My question is: how can I access files of domain A? I tried to visit http://X.Y.Z.C/A/ but met "404" error. How can I access folder of my domain directly from IP address?
*Of course IP is different than X.Y.Z.C and domain isn't "A".*

Answer (score 0):

Veru first thing you need to check is the `DocumentRoot` for X.Y.Z.C. You can check it in the apache conf file. Then for eg. you find it to be `/home/xyz/public_html/any_folder`, you would need to place the sub-directory inside `/home/xyz/public_html/any_folder`. Then you can try checking http://x.y.z.c/A/.

If this does not help, please check the apache error logs and post it here.

Comment: I am really sorry, I was wrong. I dont have access to shell. My server/hosting is provided by Hetzner... I do not have any way to check this...

Comment: Do you have access to cPanel?

Comment: Yes I do have it

Comment: Visit http://x.y.z.c/A/ & check the error log from cpanel. Let me know what it says.